# PrimeFaces.widget.InputText is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, primefaces

This is a javascript error I have every time the tomcat server is restarted.
After the page is refreshed there is no error any more.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your ajax-loaded primeface components as below and the problem is solved. 
This is because primefaces doesn't load all the widget's javasripts at the first load of the page, you have to force it to load the libs for your ajax-loaded widgets.

```
    <p:accordionPanel rendered="false" />
    <p:inputText rendered="false" />
    <p:inputMask rendered="false" />
    <p:autoComplete rendered="false"/>
```

Comment: This is interesting. Why doesn't Primefaces load these javascripts?